# How do I restrict a Perforce sync operation to only those files in a specific changelist?

Tags: perforce

I thought I could use P4 sync -f @Changelist# to sync only those files in Changelist#, but it is syncing the entire directory.  How can I limit the sync to only the files in Changelist#?

Answer (score 9):

If you want to limit a sync to only the files in a specific changelist, you can do the following:

```
$> p4 sync @changelist,@changelist
```

E.g.

```
$> p4 sync @604286,@604286
```

Comment: How is this different from p4 sync @=changelist?

Comment: It's not (assuming a submitted changelist).

Answer (score 9):

To sync only the files contained in a changelist, you can use the `@=` syntax:

```
p4 sync @=12345
```

Comment: @= is not in the perforce docs.... https://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/cmdref/p4_sync.html ... hmmm, the perforce docs are just weak in terms of examples. That syntax IS on this page: https://www.perforce.com/perforce/r16.1/manuals/cmdref/filespecs.html

Answer (score 2):

If I understand the question correctly - You already have a tree with some files. Now there is a new change-list and you want your tree to be updated in such a way that only files listed in this new change list are synced leaving rest of the tree intact/unaffected.

If this is the case then answer is - p4 sync @=changelist. But just to be safe first try with p4 sync -n @=changelist option.

If you try with p4 sync @changelist you will see that your whole tree is updated/deleted. Just try with

p4 sync -n @changelist | more

Answer (score 1):

To sum up the other answers and add one of my own: roll 1d3 and choose from this table.

1. `p4 sync -f @=CHANGE`
2. `p4 sync -f @CHANGE,CHANGE`
3. `p4 -F %depotFile%%depotRev% files @CHANGE,CHANGE | p4 -x - sync -f`

Comment: what does "roll 1d3" mean ?

Comment: roll a six sided die, divide the result by two (rounding up).